# Problem with update to Keil uVision 5 with STM32F4 discovery

Tags: c, embedded, arm, stm32f4, keil

My dev system doesnt work in Keil with STM32F4 discovery (STM32F407VG). I am using uVision 5. All my drivers are up to date. The code gets compiled without any errors, however, I cant get the Logic Analyzer to show any data. With the board, the core clock is 16 MHz. I have all combinations of core Clocks in the Trace Tab. The weird part is that the same settings and code seems to work with uVision 4 with 16 MHz as the core clock in Trace Tab. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong in uVision 5?

Comment: As pointed out below, this has nothing to do with the logic analyzer.  Can you edit the question and title to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

After spending the hole afternoon, I finally managed to solve the issue. 
In my case, I was using the STM32F334 Discovery kit.

There is a Solder Pad that must be closed in order to be able to trace variables. (SB17 in STM32F334 Discovery kit).

by default, this is open. 
I just soldered the pad, and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and it has annoyed me all day!

I have fixed it now though - basically you need to set the core clock up properly in uVision 5. In earlier versions (up to 5.10 or so) you used to be able to do this in `system_stm32f4xx.c` with `PLL_M` and `PLL_Q #define`s (8 and 7 respectively) - however in later versions (I am using v5.15) it seems this has been taken away.  You now have to set the clock up with something like:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void) 
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the
     device is clocked below the maximum system frequency (see datasheet). */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /* Enable HSE Oscillator and activate PLL with HSE as source */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

  /* Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2
     clocks dividers */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 |
                                RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5);
}
```

Which seems to work for me to set the SystemCoreClock running at 168MHz (which is what it should be).

I can get the logic analyser working and also the event trace for RTOS code.

Hope this helps - and if there is an easier way to do this I would be very glad to hear it!